# Datatable select event not triggering

Tags: datatables-1.10

I have this following code to fetch data from database and display as table.

```
var tables = $('#factsTable')
.DataTable({
    "aProcessing": true,
    "aServerSide": true,
    "ajax": "includes/get-infacts.php",
})
.on('preInit.dt', function (e, settings) {
    console.log('preInit.dt');
})
.on('init.dt', function () {
    console.log('init.dt');
})
.on('draw.dt', function () {
    console.log('draw.dt');
})
.on('search.dt', function () {
    console.log('search.dt');
})
.on('select', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
    console.log('data table select');
});
```

In this code all the other event listeners are working for me except 'select' listener.

I don't know why is not working.

Comment: You need to have `select: true` in your options, otherwise no selection is performed and no event is fired

Comment: @davidkonrad yeah. it worked. thanks

Answer (score 1):

"**.dt**" is missing..

....
    .on('select.dt', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
    console.log('data table select');